# Rendering text inside, not outside, of absolutely positioned span?

Tags: html, css

In the following example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Test Button</title>
    <style type="text/css">
.myline {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 96%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  height: 8vh;
  padding-top: 0vh;
  border-bottom: 0.3vh black;
  border-style: none none solid none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 8vh;
  position:relative;
}
span.testbutton {
  width: 5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -0.75em;
  background-color: #EEE;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="myline">
<span class="testbutton">DO IT</span>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

... I would expect the text to be rendered inside the `<span>`, but this is how Firefox 44 renders it:

[image: testbutton.png]

As seen in the picture above, the text is *below* the `<span>` - not inside it, as I expected?

If I remove the `position:absolute;` from `span.testbutton`, then the text is inside - but then I also cannot use `right:0;`.

How can I fix my code so the text positions inside the span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [`line-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) at the same `height` of your element.

```
line-height: 1.5em;
```

Comment: It works @PhiterFernandes - thanks a lot! Added the code to `span.testbutton` class... I'm accepting this as soon as the countdown expires `:)` cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

I have two solution

First Solution

```
  span.testbutton {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin-top: -19px;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 5em;
 }
```

Second Solution

```
span.testbutton { text-align: center; line-height: 1.5em; }
```